# refs(object) returning 3 even for new objects

Tags: r

I created a new variable m. When I check for the number of references in memory, my system is showing me 3 for some reason.

```
m <- 55
refs(m)
```

I get the same result even for .Internal(inspect)

Help!

Answer (score 0):

R doesn't do full reference counting.  Since your object is named, it is not safe to modify it, and that is being displayed as a reference count of 3.

Comment: What other systems?  Please post something reproducible.